# Java use 2 different object types as a field in a class

Tags: java, inheritance

I have a class that can take different objects as a field to serve a similar purpose as below;

```
public class Project {
    private int id;
    private String title;
    private String description;

    private Implementer implementer;
    .....
}
```

The implementer can be an individual (with fields such as firstName, lastName etc) or a company (with fields like companyName, industry etc). How do I make the implementer reference these two types (Individual and company). Note I do not want them to extend a common base class as they have no common fields.

Thanks

Comment: How can I make both classes implementing the interface be targetEntities in a ManyToOne relationships. I have already annotated them with @Entity but i get  an error: "implementor references an unknown entity"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a marker [interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/createinterface.html):

```
public interface Implementor {
}
```

Change classes to *implement* this interface:

```
public class Company implements Implementor {
    ...
}

public class Individual implements Implementor {
    ...
}
```

Now both of the following assignments are valid:

```
Implementor implementor;
...
implementor = new Company();
implementor = new Individual();
```